# jquery POST callback doesn't work without 'type' param

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am doing a `POST` call and want to handle `error`as well, however the `success` callback does not call if the 'type' param is not put in.

I have tried in following ways.

This works, but since I also want to handle the error part I cannot use this.

```
$.post(myurl, {
  mydatatobesent
}, function(resp) {
  console.log("done is called");
  resolve(true);
}, "text");
```

Other trials:

```js
$.post(myurl, {
  mydatatobesent
}, function(resp) {
  console.log("done is called");
  resolve(true);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("error is called");
  reject(error);
}, "text");


$.post(myurl, {
  mydatatobesent
}, function(resp) {
  console.log("done is called");
  resolve(true);
}, "text", function(error) {
  console.log("error is called");
  reject(error);
});


$.post(myurl, {
  mydatatobesent
}).done(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp)
}).fail(function(fail) {
  console.log(fail
});


$.post(myurl, {
  mydatatobesent
}, "text").done(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp)
}).fail(function(fail) {
  console.log(fail
});
```

**UPDATE** : On the last trial, `fail` handler is called.

> CONSOLE

[image]

> UPDATE

[image]
[image]

Comment: `This works, but since I also want to handle the error part I cannot use this.` That's not true. Attach a `fail()` handler.

Comment: my first trial has the fail() handler, am I doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: Your first doesn't, but the last one does (`.fail(function(fail) {
  console.log(fail
})`). If that isn't working for you then you need to debug why. We can't help with that given the limited information in the question. Also note that returning `text` is not generally a good idea. Return data in a structured format, such as XML, HTML or JSON

Comment: I get the `return` part , this is to check if it works with the `fail` handler. Question. What am I missing in the last trial? even `done` is not called. Also, what more information is needed ?

Comment: We need details of any errors in the console, the state of the request in the network tab and also the full response text (note: not the *expected* response, the *actual* response)

Comment: @freedomn-m currently, it shouldn't hit `fail()` and should go to `done()`, but that is not called.

Comment: sigh! I'll update it with a `console log` to prove i!

Comment: on the last one, you are missing a paranthesis "console.log(fail"

Comment: @freedomn-m I apologize if my question was not clear when I asked it. I want to implement `fail()` to handle errors but when I do use it, `success` callback is not called without 'type` param. Also, since the `status` code in `200` , shouldnt it go to `done()` ? So I think my current issue is, it the server call responds with 200, why is `fail` called? I take my attitude back. Appreciate your help.

Comment: TBH, I suspect I misinterpreted the question and reviewed it, which is why I removed my comments.  Summary: With dataType you get success, without, you get fail() but with no server side changes. Sounds like jquery is failing to convert the response (eg response that looks like json but fails to deserialise).   Hence using `text` as datatype (no deserialisation).     Try the `$.post(url, data, dataType).done().success()` overload.

Comment: Using 'text' as datatype did not work, so i converted my backend code to `json` which worked. I wonder why. Any ideas?